# Composition of Lebesgue measurable function and Invertible linear transformation is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, outer-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R} $ is a Lebesgue measurable function  and $T\in Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ then show that $f\circ T$ is also Lebesgue measurable .

For   Borel measurable functions it's easy to show  . I think  we need to use the fact that if $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set  then $E=B\cup N$ where $B$ is a $F_\sigma$ set i.e Borel set and $N$ is set with outer measure $0$ and $N\subset F$ where $F$ is a Borel set with measure zero , last line comes from the fact that Lebesgue measure is completion of Borel Measure .

There is similar question :
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R} $ is a Lebesgue measurable function  and $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism , then show that $f\circ T$ is also Lebesgue measurable .

Comment: See my answer for the case where $T$ is linear. Can you adopt that technique to the case where $T$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism? Recall the formula $\lambda(F(U)) = \int_{ F(U) } \, d\lambda = \int_U | \det DF | \, d\lambda$ when $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a Borel function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g = f$ ae. Let $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the null set where this equality fails. Then $M := T^{-1}(N)$ is a null set: If $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure, then
$$\lambda( T^{-1}(N) ) = | \det T^{-1} | \lambda(N) = 0$$
since $T$ is linear and invertible. For $x \notin M$ one has $Tx \notin N$, hence $g(Tx) = f(Tx)$. So $g \circ T = f \circ T$ ae. and $g \circ T$ is Borel by reasons you know. So $f \circ T$ is measurable since it equals ae. the Borel function $g \circ T$.

Comment: Why such a Borel measurable function $g$ exists which is equal to $f$ almost everywhere?

Comment: And one more question $N$ is both Lebesgue measurable and Borel measurable?

Comment: If a function is almost everywhere Borel measurable then it's also Lebesgue measurable?